# Ethernet eVC: Inject LPI with no normal IDLEs after packet

Tags: ethernet, specman, e, cadence

I simply wanted to achieve this scenario in GMII:

```
         _   _   _   _   _   _   _   _   
TX_CLK  | |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_
         ___________
TX_EN               \___________________
         ___________ ___________________
TX_D     ___________X_____0x01__________
                     ___________________
TX_ER    ___________/
```

Note the exact timing that LPI is initiated in the waveform above (no normal IDLEs after the packet ends). In the Ethernet eVC (version VIPCAT 11.30), I can't find in the available documentation (and anywhere else) how to control the LPI to be sent in that timing. It always waits for one cycle before it sends the LPI:

```
         _   _   _   _   _   _   _   _   
TX_CLK  | |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_
         ___________
TX_EN               \___________________
         ___________ ___________________
TX_D     ___________X_____0x01__________
                        ________________
TX_ER    ______________/
```

Any idea how to do this as a `vr_enet_seq`?

Comment: Maybe ask Cadence about this.

Comment: I've completely forgotten about this query. Anyway, I did ask Cadence and they provided a somewhat lower level methodology of doing the above scenario: one has to crudely modify the packet to insert the LPIs.